# Form.Load event doesn't fire

Tags: winforms, events, f#

A form has been created. It can be seen, but 'Load' event doesn't fire. This is the simplest case:

```
type Program() as this =
   let form_ = new Form(Visible=true, Text="Some Caption", Width=1024, Height=768)

   do
      form_.Load.Add(this.OnFormLoad)     
      form_.Show()

   member x.OnFormLoad(e) = 
      Trace.WriteLine("OnFormLoad() entering...")

   member x.form = form_

#if COMPILED
[<STAThread()>]
let program = new Program()
Application.Run(program.form)
#endif
```

Where am I wrong in this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing `Visible=true` from the call that constructs the form.

I think that when you set `Visible` to `true`, the form gets immediately created and loaded, so the `Load` event is triggered during the form construction (before you setup the handler). I would also remove the call `form_.Show()`. I think the form will be opened by `Application.Run`.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! After removing 'Visible=true' all works.  Thanks a lot.